# Weird overflow on UITableView with an iAd banner

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, iad

I added an iAd banner banner to my view (which is a Table View). But, unfortunately, there is a weird blank space at the end of the table view when the banner loads (everything is good until the banner is loaded and displayed).

Here's a capture showing that blank space :

[image]

To displays the banner, I just added `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` in the viewDidLoad() method

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Looks like disabling the transparency of the tab bar solved the problem. So, it seems to be one of the numerous bug due to the transparency... But, the fact is that I like the transparency of the tab bar :/
Any idea on how to fix this problem while keeping the transparency ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the gap appears to be the same size as the ad banner, (without seeing your code) I would guess that the tableview's constraint is not set properly. Can you check what the bottom constraint is set to?

If the ad banner is hidden behind the tabbar control and then slides up, you can set the bottom constraint of the tableview to the top of the ad banner with a value of 0. This way the tableview will resize as the ad banner slides up.

Without knowing your setup I can't say for sure, so reply with what your layout constraints are and I can help you tackle it :)

Comment: Hum. My code is in my message... It's just a native UITableView... I dropped a UITableView from IB into my Storyboard and that's it...

Comment: Where is the ad banner added to the interface?

Comment: Here : self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

Comment: Since you seems to don't know this implementation of UIViewController : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/canDisplayBannerAds

Comment: When the banner is added it is bumping your content up by the size of the banner. You need to set constraints on your table view so that it knows to stay tied to the bottom layout. Do you know how to add constraints?

Comment: As I see, the content is "bumped up" by two times the size of the banner. Yes I know how to add constraints, but I don't think it will change anything, because without the transparency of the tab bar, there is no problem. But, I will still give it a try tomorrow.